# libGDX font being drawn out of the viewport

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm having problems to draw some text in the screen, and I found out that depending on the viewport size, the text may get out of the display despite being calculating the coordinates as the center of the screen. Here's the code, it is a just slightly modified project as created by libgdxgenerator by default:

```
package net.iberdroid.libgdxtestfonts;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.FitViewport;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.Viewport;

public class LibGdxTestFonts extends ApplicationAdapter {
    SpriteBatch batch;
    Texture img;
    BitmapFont defaultFont;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private Viewport viewport;
    private float textY;
    private float textX;

    @Override
    public void create() {
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        viewport = new FitViewport(
                640,
                480,
                camera);
        camera.setToOrtho(false);
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        img = new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
        defaultFont = new BitmapFont();
        textX = viewport.getWorldWidth() / 2;
        textY = viewport.getWorldHeight() / 2;
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        batch.begin();
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        defaultFont.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        Gdx.app.log("render", String.format("TextX: %f TextY: %f", textX, textY));
        defaultFont.draw(batch, "HELLO WORLD!", textX, textY);
        batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        batch.dispose();
        img.dispose();
    }
}
```

As far as I understand, that should draw a HELLO WORLD! text starting around the center of the screen. And it actually does it with that viewport size. Now, if you try with a bigger viewport, let's say 800x600, the text will move to the right and top, if try even with higher values, it will become a point in which the text will get out the boundaries of the screen by the top-right corner.

The same happens in the opposite direction. The smaller viewport you try, the further from the center and closer to the bottom-left corner the text will appear, until it eventually get out the boundaries too.

So either I am failing to grasp something here, or the BitMap.draw method seems to be ignoring the viewport size and using others that I cannot figure out.

If someone else does it, please, make me know.

Thanks a lot in advance!

P.S. I've tried also with a Hiero generated font and had the same issue.

Comment: I presume this has to do with the fitviewport. What is the output of the log function in render?

Comment: The expected one, that's half of the width and half of the height, so 320, 240 with a viewport size of 640x480, 400x300 with 800x600, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this seems to solve the problem with the position, though I still have a problem with the scale, but that's a different issue.

```
@Override public void resize (int width, int height) {
    viewport.update(width, height, true);
}
```